# How do I get ligatures in Google Font API to display in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, fonts, ligature

I'm using [Google Font API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/) to display my website logo. (See top of [stolencamerafinder.com](http://www.stolencamerafinder.com/))

In Chrome the letters 'f' and 'i' appear seperately, but in FireFox, they are a nice joined [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligatures)

How do I force Chrome to use the ligature?

If I use the ligature ascii character (ﬁ) in the html then it doesn't use the font, it falls back to arial, yet the font ([OFL Sorts Mill Goudy TT](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=OFL%20Sorts%20Mill%20Goudy%20TT)) must support that ligature since firefox displays it.

**Update**: I ended up ditching Google font API in favour of plain @font-face. More choice on fontsquirrel.com anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: This feature isn't implemented yet.

Long answer: Take a look at http://crbug.com/22240 ( http://crbug.com/64479 might also be interesting).

Comment: I understand that chrome doesn't replace "fi" for the unicode ligature character like firefox does. What I don't understand is why when I replace it manually in the source, for the html entity "&#64257;" or just the character "ﬁ" it doesn't work (in either browser). _How_ does firefox find the ligature to display? If I understood how firefox did it, perhaps I could force chrome to do the same...

Comment: I can't even find the ligature char in the font on fontsquirrel.com but I suppose the font could be slightly different to the one google font api uses. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Sorts-Mill-Goudy

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that in **webkit browsers** [this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#propdef-font-variant-ligatures) property wasn't yet devoloped?
Or is it a problem of the type of font used by webkit browsers? (`TrueType`, `Woff` instead of `Opentype`)?

EDIT: In Safari [this works](http://www.aestheticallyloyal.com/public/optimize-legibility/) with some fonts that support ligatures.
For example it works with the default browser font (Times on Mac Os X), while it doesn't work with a couple of Google fonts I was trying with `@font-face` CSS feature.